# Painting from listener

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have a component listener that is a bit complex. It has a lot of calculating that depends on current state of the GUI (component heights, to be specific).

As far as I know, listeners are executed in a thread separate from EDT which takes care of the GUI, so repaint and validate methods are execute only after the listener has executed it's code. Is there a way to repaint immedatley from the listeners thread?

Due to complexity of the listener, SwingWorker is NOT an option...

Comment: Listeners are called in the EDT. It's just that `repaint()` *schedules* a paint operation. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintImmediately%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29

Comment: Down-voted for discarding out of hand the proper solution. Sorry, but not only is SwingWorker an option, it in fact is your ***best*** option. Complexity of the listener has nothing to do with this other than perhaps suggesting to you to refactor your code so you don't have to ignore use of SwingWorker.

Comment: Removed down-vote, but again, if you're going to avoid the best solution, I recommend you tell us more about why.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, repaint & invalidate or among he hand full of methods that are considered thread safe, although I tend to use [SwingUtilities.invokeLater](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable))/[invokeAndWait](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeAndWait(java.lang.Runnable)) anyways, I'm paranoid like that ;)

Comment: @Mad: `repaint()` is thread safe, but I've not heard that `invalidate()` is and I'd be surprised if it were. But regardless, if the OP is running something on the event thread that takes some time, it will stomp on the EDT and prevent responsiveness. Edit: a review of the API shows no indication that `invalidate()` or `revalidate()` are thread safe.

Comment: @hovercraftfullofeels I agree with not been able to find evidence about thread safe for invalidate, I can't find any evidence for repaint either :P. As to the OPs problem, I agree. There is No problem

Comment: @MadP: on reviewing his past posts, I'm betting that he's stating `"Due to complexity of the listener, SwingWorker is NOT an option..."` because he simply doesn't understand how to use SwingWorker, but I'm also betting that we'll never know because he appears to have abandoned this question and moved on to [the next](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12657070/ms-word-like-page-managment).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels It appears to be a case of "overwhelm evidence against - ignore"...

Answer (score 1):

I think your understanding is flawed.  All events triggered by the system are dispatched from the thread they were triggered.  That is, if you manually call `fireXxxEvent` from a different thread THEN it will notify it's listeners from that thread context.  However, all system triggered events (mouse and key events for example) will occur from within the EDT.

Here's a simple test...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            }

            JButton button =  new JButton("Click me");
            button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("Am I on the EDT = " + EventQueue.isDispatchThread());
                }
            });

            JLabel label = new JLabel("Click me");
            label.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("Am I on the EDT = " + EventQueue.isDispatchThread());
                }

            });

            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            frame.add(label, gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            frame.add(button, gbc);

            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);

        }
    });

}
```

Hovercrafts point is valid.  Any time consuming tasks should be executed in the background off the EDT.

You should re-sync with the EDT using SwingUtilities.invokeLater/invokeAndWait where appropriate.